# Displaying number of textboxes based on columns inside datagridview

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

I'm trying to create a number of textboxes based on the row's cell value inside a datagridview and fill the textboxes with the each of the value. I have it so it grabs all the data so far (used `MessageBox.Show(textBox.text)`) and it shows as expected. However, when I try to create the textboxes, it only creates one (that I can see on the windows form application).

Here is my code for the click event:

```
 qbcDataGridView.RowHeaderMouseClick += (object sender, DataGridViewCellMouseEventArgs e) =>
 {
     id = Convert.ToInt32(qbcDataGridView.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[0].Value.ToString());

     // get all the columns and assign them to textboxes text
     for (int i = 0; i < qbcDataGridView.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells.Count; i++)
     {
          var textBox = new TextBox
          {
             Name = qbcDataGridView.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[i].Value.ToString(),

             Font = new Font(qbcDataGridView.Font.FontFamily, 12),

             Text = qbcDataGridView.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[i].Value.ToString(),

             Location = new Point(80, 50)
         };

         Controls.Add(textBox);

         // used for testing
         MessageBox.Show(textBox.Text);
     }
 };
```

Here is a screenshot(s) of the program in action:

Main screen -

[image]

Screen when datagridview clicked -

[image]

(I commented out the `MessageBox.Show(textBox.Text)` but it displays 3, jimmy, test, test, test, member)

I don't know if its the for loop overwriting itself but that seems unlikely as it is showing all the data via the message box. I'm leaning towards the positioning but am not entirely sure.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: You are putting them all at the same location so only the top one will show.  You do know that data can be edited inside the DGV and it will do certain validations like only allow valid dates to be entered?

Comment: that's what I thought. Yes I do know that but the user wants textboxes. :/

Comment: anything I can do to fix this?

Comment: Creating controls is *expensive* and with that comes housekeeping responsibilities.  If there are 6 columns, you should put 6 Text controls on the form.  No need to (re-re-re) create new ones every time they click and end up with a leaking app.

Comment: it can change based on the rows in the dgv, there are more fields but I'm only showing the non empty ones.

Comment: So?  It is not a complete unknown how many columns there are.  Put that many on the form, and instead of creating new controls for every click, enable/disable accordingly.  Each click does not need 6 or 8 brand new textboxes

Comment: okay, I will do that, thanks! :)

Comment: just because I would like to know, how would you go about changing the location to make them not appear on top of each other?

Comment: @user2101411 - calculate next location based on previous.

Comment: How would I do that? Sorry, new to c#

Comment: @user2101411 - edit your question to include the pictures. You've been around here long enough...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> when I try to create the textboxes, it only creates one (that I can see on the windows form application).

Its because the textboxes are overlapped. The only one that's visible is the ID cell (because its z-order is the highest).

Simply space them out so they dont sit on top of each other:

```
Location = new Point(80 + (i * 50), 50)
```